# Blazor multi-user questionaire

Tags: asp.net, blazor, multiplayer

I need to create an app thats basically functions like a multi-user realtime questionnaire or trivia.

I've gotten to the point where i've created a questionnaire and associated users to it, but i'm hitting a road block on how to go forward.

Basically what i need to do next is
For each question in the questionnaire:

1) have the server send the users a question

2) wait for all of the users to respond or a set timeout period

3) display to the users a question result page

I was wondering how i should attempt to do something like this. Any help or resources would be wonderful

Answer (score 2):

I am building a chat application that has something very similar using Server Side Blazor.

The way I did was I inject a class I created called SubscriberService:

```
@inject Services.SubscriberService SubscriberService
```

Then in my ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs I add this:

```
services.AddSingleton<SubscriberService>();
```

The Add Singleton means only 1 instance will be created for all your browser instances (users).

This makes my Subscriber Services available to all my subcribers, which is just a name, Guid Id and a callback delegate

```
#region using statements

using DataJuggler.UltimateHelper.Core;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Transactions;

#endregion

namespace BlazorChat.Services
{

    #region class SubscriberService
    /// <summary>
    /// This class is used to subscribe to services, so other windows get a notification a new message 
    /// came in.
    /// </summary>
    public class SubscriberService
    {

        #region Private Variables
        private int count;
        private Guid serverId;
        private List<SubscriberCallback> subscribers;
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new instance of a 'SubscriberService' object.
        /// </summary>
        public SubscriberService()
        {
            // Create a new Guid
            this.ServerId = Guid.NewGuid();
            Subscribers = new List<SubscriberCallback>();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods

            #region BroadcastMessage(SubscriberMessage message)
            /// <summary>
            /// This method Broadcasts a Message to everyone that ins't blocked.
            /// Note To Self: Add Blocked Feature
            /// </summary>
            public void BroadcastMessage(SubscriberMessage message)
            {
                // if the value for HasSubscribers is true
                if ((HasSubscribers) && (NullHelper.Exists(message)))
                {   
                    // Iterate the collection of SubscriberCallback objects
                    foreach (SubscriberCallback subscriber in Subscribers)
                    {
                        // if the Callback exists
                        if ((subscriber.HasCallback) && (subscriber.Id != message.FromId))
                        {
                            // to do: Add if not blocked

                            // send the message
                            subscriber.Callback(message);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            #endregion

            #region GetSubscriberNames()
            /// <summary>
            /// This method returns a list of Subscriber Names ()
            /// </summary>
            public List<string> GetSubscriberNames()
            {
                // initial value
                List<string> subscriberNames = null;

                // if the value for HasSubscribers is true
                if (HasSubscribers)
                {
                    // create the return value
                    subscriberNames = new List<string>();

                    // Get the SubscriberNamesl in alphabetical order
                    List<SubscriberCallback> sortedNames = Subscribers.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();

                    // Iterate the collection of SubscriberService objects
                    foreach (SubscriberCallback subscriber in sortedNames)
                    {
                        // Add this name
                        subscriberNames.Add(subscriber.Name);
                    }
                }

                // return value
                return subscriberNames;
            }
            #endregion

            #region Subscribe(string subscriberName)
            /// <summary>
            /// method returns a message with their id
            /// </summary>
            public SubscriberMessage Subscribe(SubscriberCallback subscriber)
            {
                // initial value
                SubscriberMessage message = null;

                // If the subscriber object exists
                if ((NullHelper.Exists(subscriber)) && (HasSubscribers))
                {
                    // Add this item
                    Subscribers.Add(subscriber);    

                    // return a test message for now
                    message = new SubscriberMessage();

                    // set the message return properties
                    message.FromName = "Subscriber Service";
                    message.FromId = ServerId;
                    message.ToName = subscriber.Name;
                    message.ToId = subscriber.Id;
                    message.Data = Subscribers.Count.ToString();
                    message.Text = "Subscribed";
                }

                // return value
                return message;
            }
            #endregion

            #region Unsubscribe(Guid id)
            /// <summary>
            /// This method Unsubscribe
            /// </summary>
            public void Unsubscribe(Guid id)
            {
                // if the value for HasSubscribers is true
                if ((HasSubscribers) && (Subscribers.Count > 0))
                {
                    // attempt to find this callback
                    SubscriberCallback callback = Subscribers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

                    // If the callback object exists
                    if (NullHelper.Exists(callback))
                    {
                        // Remove this item
                        Subscribers.Remove(callback);

                         // create a new message
                        SubscriberMessage message = new SubscriberMessage();

                        // set the message return properties
                        message.FromId = ServerId;
                        message.FromName = "Subscriber Service";
                        message.Text = callback.Name + " has left the conversation.";
                        message.ToId = Guid.Empty;
                        message.ToName = "Room";

                        // Broadcast the message to everyone
                        BroadcastMessage(message);
                    }
                }
            }
            #endregion

        #endregion

        #region Properties

            #region Count
            /// <summary>
            /// This property gets or sets the value for 'Count'.
            /// </summary>
            public int Count
            {
                get { return count; }
                set { count = value; }
            }
            #endregion

            #region HasSubscribers
            /// <summary>
            /// This property returns true if this object has a 'Subscribers'.
            /// </summary>
            public bool HasSubscribers
            {
                get
                {
                    // initial value
                    bool hasSubscribers = (this.Subscribers != null);

                    // return value
                    return hasSubscribers;
                }
            }
            #endregion

            #region ServerId
            /// <summary>
            /// This property gets or sets the value for 'ServerId'.
            /// </summary>
            public Guid ServerId
            {
                get { return serverId; }
                set { serverId = value; }
            }
            #endregion

            #region Subscribers
            /// <summary>
            /// This property gets or sets the value for 'Subscribers'.
            /// </summary>
            public List<SubscriberCallback> Subscribers
            {
                get { return subscribers; }
                set { subscribers = value; }
            }
            #endregion

        #endregion

    }
    #endregion

}
```

Here is my SubscriberCallback.cs:

```
#region using statements

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

#endregion

namespace BlazorChat
{

    #region class SubscriberCallback
    /// <summary>
    /// This class is used to register a subscriber with the ChatService
    /// </summary>
    public class SubscriberCallback
    {

        #region Private Variables
        private string name;
        private Guid id;
        private Callback callback;
        private List<Guid> blockedList;
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new instance of a SubscriberCallback instance
        /// </summary>
        public SubscriberCallback(string name)
        {
            // store the Name
            Name = name;

            // Create the Id
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();

            // create a BlockedList
            BlockedList = new List<Guid>();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods

            #region ToString()
            /// <summary>
            /// This method is used to return the Name of the Subscriber when ToString is called.
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public override string ToString()
            {
                // return the Name when ToString is called
                return this.Name;
            }
            #endregion

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        #region BlockedList
        /// <summary>
        /// This property gets or sets the value for 'BlockedList'.
        /// </summary>
        public List<Guid> BlockedList
            {
                get { return blockedList; }
                set { blockedList = value; }
            }
            #endregion

            #region Callback
            /// <summary>
            /// This property gets or sets the value for 'Callback'.
            /// </summary>
            public Callback Callback
            {
                get { return callback; }
                set { callback = value; }
            }
            #endregion

            #region HasBlockedList
            /// <summary>
            /// This property returns true if this object has a 'BlockedList'.
            /// </summary>
            public bool HasBlockedList
            {
                get
                {
                    // initial value
                    bool hasBlockedList = (this.BlockedList != null);

                    // return value
                    return hasBlockedList;
                }
            }
            #endregion

            #region HasCallback
            /// <summary>
            /// This property returns true if this object has a 'Callback'.
            /// </summary>
            public bool HasCallback
            {
                get
                {
                    // initial value
                    bool hasCallback = (this.Callback != null);

                    // return value
                    return hasCallback;
                }
            }
            #endregion

            #region HasName
            /// <summary>
            /// This property returns true if the 'Name' exists.
            /// </summary>
            public bool HasName
            {
                get
                {
                    // initial value
                    bool hasName = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Name));

                    // return value
                    return hasName;
                }
            }
            #endregion

            #region Id
            /// <summary>
            /// This property gets or sets the value for 'Id'.
            /// </summary>
            public Guid Id
            {
                get { return id; }
                set { id = value; }
            }
            #endregion

            #region Name
            /// <summary>
            /// This property gets or sets the value for 'Name'.
            /// </summary>
            public string Name
            {
                get { return name; }
                set { name = value; }
            }
            #endregion

        #endregion

    }
    #endregion

}
```

And here is my delegate class:

```
/// <summary>
/// This delegate is used by the SubscriberService to send messages to any subscribers
/// </summary>    
/// <returns></returns>
public delegate void Callback(SubscriberMessage message);
```

Then in my component I call methods like this:

```
//  Send this message to all clients
SubscriberService.BroadcastMessage(message);
```

And each client has a listen method:

```
SubscriberCallback callback = new SubscriberCallback(SubscriberName);
callback.Callback = Listen;
callback.Name = SubscriberName;

// Get a message back
SubscriberMessage message = SubscriberService.Subscribe(callback);
```

Here is my Listen method, it just waits for messages;

```
using DataJuggler.UltimateHelper.Core; // Nuget package

public void Listen(SubscriberMessage message)
{
    // if the message exists (part of DataJuggler.UltimateHelper.Core Nuget Package)
    // Same as (message != null)
    if (NullHelper.Exists(message))
    {
        // if the message contains Joined the conversation
        if ((message.Text.Contains("joined the conversation")) || 
        (message.Text.Contains("left the conversation")))
        {
            // this updates my list of 'Whose On' whenever a user joins or leaves

            // Get the Names again
            this.Names = SubscriberService.GetSubscriberNames();

            // Update the UI
            Refresh();
        }
        else
        {
            // my display message code is here
        }
    }
```

And finally here is my Subscriber message:

```
#region using statements

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

#endregion

namespace BlazorChat
{

    #region class SubscriberMessage
    /// <summary>
    /// This class is used to send information between components / pages.
    /// </summary>
    public class SubscriberMessage
    {

        #region Private Variables
        private string text;
        private Guid fromId;
        private Guid toId;
        private string fromName;
        private string toName;
        private object data;
        private string valid;
        private DateTime sent;
        private string invalidReason;
        #endregion

        #region Properties

            #region Data
            /// <summary>
            /// This property gets or sets the value for 'Data'.
            /// </summary>
            public object Data
            {
                get { return data; }
                set { data = value; }
            }
            #endregion

            #region FromId
            /// <summary>
            /// This property gets or sets the value for 'FromId'.
            /// </summary>
            public Guid FromId
            {
                get { return fromId; }
                set { fromId = value; }
            }
            #endregion

            #region FromName
            /// <summary>
            /// This property gets or sets the value for 'FromName'.
            /// </summary>
            public string FromName
            {
                get { return fromName; }
                set { fromName = value; }
            }
            #endregion

            #region HasText
            /// <summary>
            /// This property returns true if the 'Text' exists.
            /// </summary>
            public bool HasText
            {
                get
                {
                    // initial value
                    bool hasText = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Text));

                    // return value
                    return hasText;
                }
            }
            #endregion

            #region InvalidReason
            /// <summary>
            /// This property gets or sets the value for 'InvalidReason'.
            /// </summary>
            public string InvalidReason
            {
                get { return invalidReason; }
                set { invalidReason = value; }
            }
            #endregion

            #region Sent
            /// <summary>
            /// This property gets or sets the value for 'Sent'.
            /// </summary>
            public DateTime Sent
            {
                get { return sent; }
                set { sent = value; }
            }
            #endregion

            #region Text
            /// <summary>
            /// This property gets or sets the value for 'Text'.
            /// </summary>
            public string Text
            {
                get { return text; }
                set { text = value; }
            }
            #endregion

            #region ToId
            /// <summary>
            /// This property gets or sets the value for 'ToId'.
            /// </summary>
            public Guid ToId
            {
                get { return toId; }
                set { toId = value; }
            }
            #endregion

            #region ToName
            /// <summary>
            /// This property gets or sets the value for 'ToName'.
            /// </summary>
            public string ToName
            {
                get { return toName; }
                set { toName = value; }
            }
            #endregion

            #region Valid
            /// <summary>
            /// This property gets or sets the value for 'Valid'.
            /// </summary>
            public string Valid
            {
                get { return valid; }
                set { valid = value; }
            }
            #endregion

        #endregion

    }
    #endregion

}
```

BlazorChat is a sample project I am still working on as part of my Nuget package:
DataJuggler.Blazor.Components, which contains a Sprite component, ProgressBar and Validation component.

The full code is here in the Samples folder of this project if I left anything out.
https://github.com/DataJuggler/DataJuggler.Blazor.Components

Documentation and SQL scripts are missing, so sorry, its a work in progress.